# When overriding multiple interfaces, can you determine the context of the caller?

Tags: java

Given the class definition below, is there a way to tell if I'm being called as a Sender or a Receiver?

```
public class Outer {
  interface Master {
    public void connect();
  }
  interface Receiver extends Master {} 
  interface Sender extends Master {}

  private class Example implements Sender, Receiver {
    @Override
    public void connect() {
        // Sender or Receiver?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can find the caller using `StackTraceElement`. So you can know whether `connect()` calling as a `Sender` or `Receiver`

Comment: You can know that bu using "instanceof"

Comment: this instanceof {Sender,Receiver} both return true as Example is an instance of both.

Comment: @Ruchira `StackTraceElement` only gives me the class name of the caller. I don't see how I could determine if I was called as a `Sender` or a `Receiver` without knowing the internals of my calling class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot determine. The overridden method belongs to both interfaces.

[I wrote the same here](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/07/can-interface-extend-multiple.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't like this answer but that doesn't stop it from being correct. I had to deal with Sender/Receiver differentiation in a completely different fashion.

Answer (score -1):

For any interface, the implementation matters and can differ.

For your example, I am unable to see, that in which scenario, you may need to know whether  `public void connect()` is an implementation of Sender or Receiver?

Since the signature of the method is exactly same, there is no meaning of creating two interfaces at all (assuming that you do not have more methods within the interface).

Using interface in Java is all about good design practice and leveraging polymorphic behavior at runtime. But you need to be careful in designing your interfaces, they should not be confusing. In your case, the meaning of interfaces looks like:

> Master - an interface representing `connect()` method.
>
> Sender - an interface which need the `connect()` method of master +
>   may have its own methods.
>
> Receiver - an interface which need the `connect()` method of master +
>   may have its own methods.

Now when you say that Example is implementing Sender and Receiver both, then the `connect()` method implementation is that of Master interface (because this never belonged to Sender and Receiver at all).